# Building wheel for glpk (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully

Tags: libraries, glpk

I'm trying to install the glpk package using pip install glpk but it returns me this error

`Collecting glpk
Using cached glpk-0.4.7.tar.gz (161 kB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: glpk
Building wheel for glpk (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Building wheel for glpk (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [6 lines of output]
WARNING setuptools_scm.pyproject_reading toml section missing 'pyproject.toml does not contain a tool.setuptools_scm section'
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_ext
building 'glpk' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for glpk
Failed to build glpk
ERROR: Could not build wheels for glpk, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects`

I've already install the MVC 14.36 and the setup tools 8.0.3. I've also tried to download winglpk and add the glpk/win64 to the env path.
Can someone pls help me?

I was expecting to install glpk successfully after installing Microsoft Visual C++ and setup tools